# QLocalServer creates 50 named pipes with the same name

Tags: c++11, qt6

I've written a small program that sniffs the serial communication of of an equipment control software with their hardware and extracts the measured values to send it to my application that controls other functions of this testing system. For the communication between this sniffer and my application I use QLocalServer which should communicate with my application over named pipes. I've experienced that the communication is very slow and I was wondering why. Using the process explorer from sysinternals I've found out that this QLocalServer creates 50 named pipes with the same name.

Here the definition of the server:

```
server = new QLocalServer(this);
server->setMaxPendingConnections(1);
connect(server, &QLocalServer::newConnection, this, &SSRTSniffer::connectionEstablished);
```

And here the initialization in listening mode:

```
void SSRTSniffer::initServer(){
qDebug() << "Init Server";
if(serverName.isEmpty())
    return;
if(server->isListening())
{
    if(clientConnected)
    {
        client->disconnectFromServer();
        do
        {
            QEventLoop loop;
            QTimer::singleShot(50, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
            loop.exec();
        } while (clientConnected);
    }
}
server->close();
if(!server->listen(serverName))
{
    qDebug() << "Could not start server";
}}
```

And the code executed when a communication is established:

```
void SSRTSniffer::connectionEstablished(){
qDebug() << "Connected";
clientConnected = true;
client = server->nextPendingConnection();
connect(client, &QLocalSocket::disconnected, client, &QLocalSocket::deleteLater);
connect(client, &QLocalSocket::disconnected, this, &SSRTSniffer::connectionClosed);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally not an expert, but looks like the problem could come from the quit() called from singleshot() asynchronously. It forces a direct exit(0), if there were files, pipes or anything else opened or malloc()-ed, all this will still exist without proper cleanup, closure, free(). As this happens in a do-while loop I would expect a new pipe every ~50ms (singleshot, first argument). If you only have 50 pipes, you are either looking after 2,5s or your operating system does something internal limiting this number.

Comment: I've checked it, it doesn't enter into this do-while loop as it doesn't should as there are no existing connections at startup

Comment: Just looked through the documentation a bit, do you disconnect the connections created by connect()? If you don't the connection will still remain (a connection is probably a pipe, at least in this case). Does the number of pipes increase after running your program? You could try to prevent multiple connections by using Qt::UniqueConnection as the connection type. I am also not sure if you intend to connect the client to itself in connectionEstablished().

Comment: Switched to TCP. Problem solved.